# Babel 7 not including polyfills

Tags: babeljs, babel-polyfill

I am trying to transpile a webapplication using Babel v7.8.7 and Webpack v4.42.0.

The solution works in the latest version of Chrome. In Internet Explorer I am getting an error:

```
SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught.
```

If I include polyfills from a CDN the app works correctly in IE11:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

I am now wondering why Babel is not polyfilling correctly.

My index.js includes core-js polyfills:

```
import "core-js/es";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

I have set .browserslistrc to include Internet Explorer 11.

My babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
        corejs: '3.6.4'
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator"
  ]
};
```

Do you know what I am missing to have Babel polyfill correctly?